# How to add URL to PDF document using iText?

Tags: java, url, itext

I have implemented a generic method to create PDFPCell and it is fine for text fields.
Here I am looking for some code which can help me to add url (hot links).
Thanks in advance.

```
public PdfPCell createCell(String text, Font font, BaseColor bColor, int rowSpan, int colSpan, int hAlign, int vAlign) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text, font));
    cell.setBackgroundColor(bColor);
    cell.setRowspan(rowSpan);
    cell.setColspan(colSpan);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(hAlign);
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(hAlign);
    cell.setMinimumHeight(20);
    cell.setNoWrap(true);
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the whole cell to be clickable, or just the content in the cell?

Answer (score 10):

Please take a look at the [LinkInTableCell](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/adding-annotations-table-cell#1619-linkintablecell.java) example. It demonstrates two different approaches to add a link in a cell.

**Approach #1:** add the link to (part of) the phrase.

```
Phrase phrase = new Phrase();
phrase.add("The founders of iText are nominated for a ");
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("European Business Award!");
chunk.setAnchor("http://itextpdf.com/blog/european-business-award-kick-ceremony");
phrase.add(chunk);
table.addCell(phrase);
```

In this example, we create a cell with the content "The founders of iText are nominated for a European Business Award!". When you click on the text "European Business Award!", you go to [a blog post](http://itextpdf.com/blog/european-business-award-kick-ceremony).

**Approach #2: add the link to the complete cell**

In this approach we add a cell event to the cell:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Help us win a European Business Award!"));
cell.setCellEvent(new LinkInCell(
    "http://itextpdf.com/blog/help-us-win-european-business-award"));
table.addCell(cell);
```

The implementation of the cell event looks like this:

```
class LinkInCell implements PdfPCellEvent {
    protected String url;
    public LinkInCell(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle position,
        PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        PdfWriter writer = canvases[0].getPdfWriter();
        PdfAction action = new PdfAction(url);
        PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(
            writer, position, PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT, action);
        writer.addAnnotation(link);
    }
}
```

Wherever you click in the cell (not only when you click on text), you are now forwarded to [another blog post](http://itextpdf.com/blog/help-us-win-european-business-award).

If this answer was helpful, you might want to give my wife and I your vote for the [European Business Awards](http://www.businessawardseurope.com/vote/detail-new/belgium/15721)

Comment: Hi Bruno, How can we provide to open in new tab?

Comment: That's not covered in ISO-32000-1, hence there's no way to do this. Whatever isn't defined in the PDF specification, can't be implemented.

Comment: thank you for feedback, what about using javascript in pdf?